# How to simplify $\int_z \left( \frac{1}{z}f(z) \int_y \int_x y~\frac{f(x,y,z) }{f(z)} \,dx\, dy \right)dz$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to simplify the following integral:

$$
\int_z \left( \frac{1}{z}f(z) \int_y \int_x  y~\frac{f(x,y,z) }{f(z)} \,dx\, dy \right)dz \tag{1}
$$

where $f(x,y,z)$ is the joint density function of $x,y,z$, where $x,y,z$ are not independent, and $f(z)= \int_y \int_x f(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy$.

Can I simplify integral $(1)$ by pulling $f(z)$ out of inner the integral and cancel it with the other $f(z)$?

$$\int_z \left( \frac{1}{z} \int_{y}\int_{x} y~f(x,y,z) \,dx\, dy \right)dz $$

Comment: The notation $f(z)$ is not well-defined in light of $f(x,y,z)$..

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion with your univariate and multivariate $f$'s, you might want to write
\begin{equation}
f_Z(z) = \int_{X \times Y} f(x,y,z) \mu(dx,dy),
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure. This is standard notation for the marginal density of $Z$. You can definitely pull out $f_Z(z)$ outside of the integral, as it is effectively just a constant in the integration with respect to $x$ and $y$ as it depends on neither. What you should perhaps be more worried about is the potential singularity arising from $f_Z(z_0) = 0$ for some $z_0$, which would lead to blow-up in the interior integrals, and hence by Tonelli's theorem, the expression you have is not integrable. If the set of all such $z_0$ is null then there is no issue, but otherwise you run into problems.